# Scripted map rendering (multiple similar maps from one shapefile) using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, rendering

I would like to ask for advice on creating a **Python script** that will provide the opportunity to **render a plenty of similar maps** (with the same extent, projection, layout, color scheme and composition, but with differing titles and data used for rendering).

Say we have a single shapefile or Spatialite DB with a huge attribute table inherited from csv file like this:

[image]

I want to turn them into a set of choropleth maps like this:

[image]

So I guess that I need a script that will just:

1. Iterate through specified range of columns in the attribute table;
2. Call some (yet not written?) rendering function that will produce the choropleth map with a legend and title;
3. Dump the output to the vector formatted-file (PDF, EPS, etc.).

I'm going to use QGis for that purpose and would be glad if anyone could outline the main ideas and key QGis API functions that I can rely on at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://documentation.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/composer.html has a simple Python example. http://spatialgalaxy.net/2012/01/27/qgis-running-scripts-in-the-python-console/ has a more detailed example.